# redifine method delete or destroy in modelviewset of Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a special delete, so I cannot just use DELETE method.

this is the model:

```
class PersonalDetail(models.Model):
    icon = models.URLField(_('icon'), max_length=500, blank=True, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(_('date'), auto_now_add=True)
    checked = models.BooleanField(_('checked'), blank=True, default=False)
    priority = models.CharField(_('priority'), blank=True, max_length=1)
    preview_title = models.CharField(_('preview_title'), blank=True, max_length=100)
    preview_text = models.TextField(_('preview_text'), blank=True)
    preview_name = models.CharField(_('preview_name'), blank=True, max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(_('type'), choices=PERSONAL_DETAILS_INFO, default='Info', max_length=100, blank=False)
    content = JSONField(_('content'))
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The point is, when the "type" is `message`, `facebookpost` or `info`, then I have to delete except `icon`, `id` and `preview_title`. Until now, I could use some kind of PUT. But... when the "type" is `userdefined` then I gotta delete everything, like a normal delete.

So, I don't have idea how I can do it. I thought that maybe I could use something like `.destroy()` and override it. For example, I know how to override `perfom_create()` or `get_queryset()`, but nothing with delete.

My view looks so:

```
class PersonalDetailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PersonalDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonalDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PersonalDetail.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.request.user))

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)

    # Not delete icon, id, preview_title
```

Maybe someone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved so:

```
def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    if instance.type == 'userdefined':
        instance.delete()
    else:
        serializer = PersonalDetailSerializer(instance, data=self.request.data)

        serializer.is_valid()

        serializer.save(checked=False)
        serializer.save(preview_text='')
        serializer.save(preview_name='')
        serializer.save(content={"": ""})
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it works. If someone knows a better way, I'll appreciate an answer.